# Parsing quoted string with escape chars

Tags: antlr4

I'm having a problem parsing a list of lines of format in antlr4

```
* this is a string
*  "first"  this is "quoted"
* this is "quoted with \" "
```

I want to build a parse tree like

```
(list 
(line * (value (string this is a string))) 
(line * (value (parameter first) (string   this is) (parameter quoted))) 
(line * (value (string this is) (parameter quoted with " )))
)
```

I have an antlr4 grammar of this format

```
grammar List;
list : line+;
line : '*' (WS)+ value* NEWLINE;
value : string
      | parameter
      ;
string : ((WORD) (WS)*)+;
parameter : '"'((WORD) (WS)*)+ '"';
WORD : (~'\n')+;
WS : '\t' | ' ';
NEWLINE     : '\n';
```

But this is failing in the first character recognition of '*' itself, which baffles me.

line 1:0 mismatched input '* this is a string' expecting '*'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your lexer is too greedy. The rule

```
WORD : (~'\n')+;
```

matches almost everything. This causes the lexer to produce the following tokens for your input:

- token 1: `WORD` (`* this is a string`)
- token 2: `NEWLINE`
- token 3: `WORD` (`*  "first"  this is "quoted")
- token 4: `NEWLINE`
- token 5: `WORD` (`* this is "quoted with \" "`)

Yes, that is correct: only `WORD` and `NEWLINE` tokens. ANTLR's lexer tries to construct tokens with as much characters as possible, it does not "listen" to what the parser is trying to match.

The error message:

> line 1:0 mismatched input '* this is a string' expecting '*'

is telling you this: on line 1, index 0 the token with text `'* this is a string'` (type `WORD`) is encountered, but the parser is trying to match the token: `'*'`

Try something like this instead:

```
grammar List;

parse
 : NEWLINE* list* NEWLINE* EOF
 ;

list
 : item (NEWLINE item)*
 ;

item
 : '*' (STRING | WORD)* 
 ;

BULLET : '*';
STRING : '"' (~[\\"] | '\\' [\\"])* '"';
WORD : ~[ \t\r\n"*]+;
NEWLINE : '\r'? '\n' | '\r';
SPACE : [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

which parses your example input as follows:

```
(parse 
  (list 
    (item 
      * this is a string) \n 
    (item 
      * "first" this is "quoted") \n 
    (item 
      * this is "quoted with \" ")) 
   \n 
  <EOF>)
```